# Cannot read property "send" of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I have this thing, which if you write in the console, it sends the message to a specific channel, in my case, that specific channel is a user's DMs, but.. I get the cannot read property "send" of undefined error?

```js
let y = process.openStdin()
y.addListener('data', res => {
    let x = res.toString().trim().split(/ +/g)
    const dmper = client.users.cache.get("704996899132014652");
    dmper.send(x.join(' '));
})
```

And the error is;

```
/home/runner/ottawa-v2/index.js:14
dmper.send(x.join(' '));
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/home/runner/ottawa-v2/index.js:14:9)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TTY.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
```

Comment: Is the user on the same server as the bot?

Comment: Yes they are on the same server.

Comment: Well, I just testet it and it works for me. If `dmper` is `undefined`, the specific user can't be found. So either the user isn't on the same server as the bot, or the ID is invalid.

Comment: It can read dmper, but it cannot read send.

Comment: No, it can't: `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`. Try adding a check like `if (!dmper) console.log("cant find user");` and you'll see it's undefined.

Comment: Oh.. so how do I fix this?

Comment: Make sure the ID is correct. Otherwise your code looks fine. [It works for me](https://imgur.com/mTnQjcv).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible mistakes in your code. The first one being that the specific ID is incorrect, the other one being that the user this ID belongs to is not cached, resulting in him not being a part of the `client.users.cache` collection. In the first case, simply make sure the ID is correct. In the 2nd case you could replace the `client.users.cache.get()` method with `client.users.fetch()` that results in you getting the User object of the ID regardless of whether the user is cached or not.

**Note**: `fetch()` returns a promise, therefore the method requires to be awaited while defining its outcome.

#### Final Code with `.fetch()`

```js
let y = process.openStdin()
y.addListener('data', res => {
    let x = res.toString().trim().split(/ +/g)
    const dmper = await client.users.fetch("704996899132014652");
    dmper.send(x.join(' '));
})
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it

Comment: Nope... "dmpr.send"  is not a function

Comment: You typed `dmpr` instead of `dmper`.

Answer (score 0):

To use the send() method you need to have a channel or a user object.
In this case dmpr is undefined, something went wrong with `client.users.cache.get();` it could be the ID you provided; but I suggest you to use:

```
client.users.fetch(ID).then(user => {
    user.send(yourMessage);
});
```